# One signal push notification rewrite text

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, onesignal

Can we modify the text of **push notification** after certain time using [One-Signal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference)?

## **For example:**

I get the push saying ***"A User is calling"***, after certain time, if the push-notification is not opened, i would like to change the same push text to ***"You missed the call from User"***.

I couldn't find any API to do that from [One-Signal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference).

I tried clearing particular notification. There was only:

```
OneSignal.clearOneSignalNotifications();
```

which apparently is not functional.

I have tried using the **`collapse_id`** to update the existing notification, but it is not working either. Here is the code i use in the node part:

```
app.post('/pushNotification', function(request, response) {
var userId = request.query.callerId;
var pushId = request.query.pushId;
var callerName = request.query.callerName;
var callerImage = request.query.callerImage;
var sendNotification = function(data) {
  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization": "Basic keywhichisworking"
  };

  var options = {
    host: "onesignal.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/api/v1/notifications",
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers
  };

  var https = require('https');
  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log("Response:");
      var one_signal_resp = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
      response.json({data: one_signal_resp,
        message:'success from onesignal'});
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    response.json({error: e,
        message:'error from onesignal'});
    console.log("ERROR:");
    console.log(e);
  });

  req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
  req.end();
};

var message = { 
  app_id: "myappidwhichisworking",
  contents: {'en': callerName+' is Calling..',
        'es': 'Cuerpo de la notificación'},
  include_player_ids :[pushId],
  large_icon:"www/img/pushImage.png",
  small_icon:"sym_action_call",
  big_picture:callerImage,
  collapse_id: 'call',//static collapse_id
  android_sound:"beep30",
  data:{"callerId":userId,"callerName":callerName,"callerImage":callerImage,"isCall":true,"isMessage":false}, 
};


sendNotification(message);
})
```

I have used the static **`collapse_id`** to update the previous notification. I also tried using **`collapse_key`** just in case, but it is giving me multiple push notification instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I don't understand you correctly, but... Is this possible? I mean, when you send a push notification and is received from the user, I think that you don't have the control about it. Is the user who can open, delete, etc etc.. Is there a service that implements it? An approach: maybe you can do a hack with the Stacking Notifications, take a look here https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html

Comment: Hi @jos , there are roundways like stacking the notification, instead of stacking the notification, i would want the recent to stay which is like removing the current push notification and replacing it with a new push. Infact if i can remove that particular notification i can use cordova's local push to have the push changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collapse_id` on the OneSignal [notification create](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification) REST API call to update existing notifications with the same id. However this currently only works if the notification hasn't already been display on the device to the user on Android. (This currently works on iOS 10 devices) You can follow the native SDK [issue #147](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/147) for progress on this for Android and will be included in the Cordova SDK shortly after a release.

If you need support before this you can follow the issue's recommendation on overriding `androidNotificationId`. However note this will require Android Native Java code to do this with Cordova.

Comment: Hi @jkasten, i have tried using collapse_id , but it is not working as well. Please see my edit.